# Writing locally closed immersion as open immersion followed by closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $i\colon X\to Y$ be a closed immersion and let $j\colon Y\to Z$ be an open immersion of schemes. Under which assumptions, may I write the  composition $j\circ i$ as an open immersion followed by a closed immersion?

I am particularly interested in why this works for the following canonical composition:
$$
\operatorname{Spec}k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_k \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k
$$
where $k$ is a field and $I\subset k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is an ideal.

Comment: In your special case, homogenise the ideal $I$ with respect to $X_{n+1}$ to get an ideal $\overline{I}$. Then the closed subset of $\mathbf P^n$ you need is the vanishing set of $\overline{I}$.

Comment: @Nefertiti Thanks, so $V_+(\bar{I}) \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is closed and the above map identifies $\operatorname{Spec}k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$ (topologically) with $V_+(\bar{I})\cap D_+(X_{n+1})$. Then I endow $V_+(\bar{I})$ with the closed subscheme structure induced by $\operatorname{Proj}k[X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}]/\bar{I}$ to obtain an isomorphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec}k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I \cong D_+(X_{n+1}) \cap V_+(\bar{I})$, which is open in the closed subscheme $V_+(\bar{I})$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true under very general assumptions, see [Stacks/01IM](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IM) and [Stacks/07RJ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RJ). This is also Exercise 2.3.2 in Qing Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.

It is sufficient to e.g. assume that $Z$ is locally Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks, I do not yet know about ideal sheaves; in my version os Liu's book Exercise 2.3.2 is something about showing that the restriction morphism is flat in the case of an affine open subscheme of an affine scheme.

Comment: @user363120: It's on page 96. Maybe I misunderstood the numbering?